# Method to get the corresponding layer of a given feature:source.Vector.getSource() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using Angular and OpenLayers3 to include a map in my web-application.

I am trying to find out which layer a given feature belongs to. I am doing this because I want to remove a selected feature from the map. As I have different layers for different features, I cannot be too sure which layer I have to remove the feature from.

Here are some important lines to understand this code-extract:

```
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/vector';
import Feature from 'ol/feature';
[...]
map: ol.Map;
```

My method looks like this:

```
  get_LayerOfFeature(feature: Feature): VectorSource {
    //Iterate over all layers of the map
    for (let x of this.map.getLayers().getArray()) {
      let source: VectorSource = x.getSource();
      let features: Feature[] = source.getFeatures();
      //Iterate over all features of the vector-source
      for (let y of features) {
        if (y == feature) {
          return x;
        }
      }
    }
    //Given features does not belong to any existing vector-source
    return null;
  }
```

My current problem is that the compiler complains about this line:

```
let source: VectorSource = x.getSource();
```

It gives me the following error:

> Property 'getSource' does not exist on type 'Base'

The problem seems to be that .getLayers() returns a collection of Bases. Using .getArray() I get an Array of Bases.

Then I had a look at its docs: [Openlayers Docs: Base](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Base.html)

This class is an abstract class and obviously does not include the function "getSource". Yet, there is the subclass "ol.layer.Layer" which is exactly what I am looking for. This class also includes the getSource() method that I want to use.

What I tried:

Casting the x-element of the for-each-loop and saving it to a new variable:

```
let x2: VectorLayer = <VectorLayer>x;
let source: VectorSource = x2.getSource();
```

At least this did not throw an error during the compilation. However, I get the following runtime-error:

> ERROR TypeError: source.getFeatures is not a function

Is the problem actually that I did not cast the Base-object to a vector-source-object properly? It looks like the object (in my case the layer) is missing the required method even though it is supposed to be there according to the docs.

Comment: Seems like there should also be a `getFeatureById(id)` function on `VectorSource`, meaning you should be able to skip second `for`-loop and just do `source.getFeatureById(feature.getId());`.

Comment: Maybe you need to do `if(x instanceof VectorLayer) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for my comments:

```
get_LayerOfFeature(feature: Feature): VectorSource {
  let id = feature.getId();
  for (let x of this.map.getLayers().getArray()) {
    if(x instanceof VectorLayer) {
      let source: VectorSource = x.getSource();
      let feat: Feature = source.getFeatureById(id);
      if(feat !== undefined && feat !== null) {
        return source;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: The compiler still complains about the "x.getSource()"-part. It says: Property "getSource" does not exist on type "Base".

Comment: @MirkoR. That's wierd..It should know the type when checking for `instanceof`, within the `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was:

Obviously, the map.getLayers()-method returns all layers that are bound to the map. That means that it also returns the tile-layer. This tile-layer is an [ol.layer.Tile](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html)

This class does not include the getSource()-method. In order to fix it, I made sure, that this tile-layer is not included in the for-each-loop:

```
  get_LayerOfFeature(feature: Feature): VectorSource {

    let featureArray: Feature[] = this.map.getLayers().getArray();
    for(var i = 1; i<featureArray.length; i++ ) {
      let source = featureArray[i].getSource();
      for(let x of source.getFeatures()) {
        if(x==feature) {
          console.log(featureArray[i]);
          return featureArray[i]
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Starting at the second entry of the list is probably not a really good solution, as the returned Array does not have to be ordered. In my case, the Tile-Layer was always in the first position of the array.